# Javascript: getBBox() in Raphaël is always 0

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to get the width and height of a text created with Raphaël but unfortunately, the width and height is always 0. My code is pretty simple:

```
var r = new Raphael(document.getElementById("raphael"), 600, 400);
var t = r.text(50, 50, "Hello World!").attr({'text-anchor': 'start'});
alert(t.getBBox()); // Everything is 0
alert(t.getBBox().width); // Outputs 0
alert(t.getBBox().height); // Outputs 0
```

I'm using the latest version of Raphaël (2.2.1) and already tried different browsers (Vivaldi 1.3.551, FireFox 48, IE 11...) but always the same result.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me at http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/jnyLnk4j/ (Chrome 55, firefox 47). Sure your div id is correct ?

Comment: Yep, it's also working for me, BUT... I figured out the problem. The `<div id="raphael">` is inside another div: `<div style="display: none;">` and this div is set to visible when the page was loaded completely. When removing the `"display: none"` statement, getBBox() returns a valid size...